# Azerothcore worldserver won't start win10

Tags: azerothcore

Worldserver crash after :

```
AC>worldserver process priority class set to HIGH

Starting up Auction House Listing thread...

Max allowed socket connections 1024

Calendar deletion of old events.

Guild Daily Cap reset.

AzerothCore rev. fcaf91b8b2af 2020-07-30 12:35:45 +0200 (master branch) (Win64, Debug) (worldserverdaemon) ready...

Calendar deletion of old events.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xtree(182) : Assertion failed: cannot dereference end map/set iterator
```

same problem in Visual studio 15/16 only different row xtree(222)/xtree(182) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWdB6.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by reconfiguring CMake CMAKE_AR from

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/**Hostx84**/x64/lib.exe
```

to

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/**Hostx64**/x64/lib.exe
```

I then recompiled and everything worked like a charm. Hope this can help you.